# Find contiguous sequence of elements in an array

Tags: swift, algorithm

After research I found only the way to get the discontiguous sequence of elements in an array.
I wonder is there an efficient way to get all the contiguous sequence of elements in an array using Swift.

Example:
For `[1, 2, 3]`, the answer would be

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
2
2 3
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two loops with list slicing to get all contiguous subsequences.

```swift
let arr = [1,2,3,4]

var res = [[Int]]()

for i in 0..<arr.count {
    for j in i..<arr.count {
        res.append(Array(arr[i...j]))
    }
}

print(res)
// [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

Comment: The temp array here is pointless

Comment: @LeoDabus good point, removed it

Answer (score 1):

Using a functional approach the solution would be something like:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4]
let contiguousSubsequences = numbers.indices.flatMap { lowerBound in
    numbers[lowerBound...].indices.map { numbers[lowerBound...$0] }
}
contiguousSubsequences  // [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

---

You can also make a generic computed property extending Collection protocol that would allow you to use it with any type of collection including Strings and SubSequences:

```
extension Collection {
    var contiguousSubsequences: [SubSequence] {
        indices.flatMap { lowerBound in
            self[lowerBound...].indices.map { self[lowerBound...$0] }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4]
let contiguousSubsequences = numbers.contiguousSubsequences
contiguousSubsequences  // [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]

let letters = "abcd"
let contiguousSubstrings = letters.contiguousSubsequences
contiguousSubstrings  // ["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c", "cd", "d"]
```